# Trying to find span element by class and text with selenium c#

Tags: selenium, c#

I want to click on Administration panel. The `<span>` contains a class attribute and inner text.

I get an error saying "unable to locate element". What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
 <div class="item-inner">
      <span class="title"> Administration </span>
      <i class="icon-arrow"></i>
  </div>
```

C# code

```
  var admi = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'title')]  [contains(text(),'Administration')]"));

  admi.Click();
```

Comment: var admi = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'title')]  [contains(text(),'Administration')]"));   Try this

Comment: have you soved this problem?i meet the same problem!

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid the use of contains as your method of finding an element.  This will mainly cause you issues later down the line when other elements unintentionally match

I would suggest you use something more like;

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='item-inner']/span[@class='title']"));
```

This example still isn't ideal, and ideally you should ask your developers to add in a unique ID for you to utilize.

Answer (score 0):

Use following Xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='title']"));
```

Also make sure variable in which you are saving the element is of WebElement type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pandas you can search by:

```
url = "YOUR_URL_HERE"

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.get(url)
result = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('screen-reader-text')
pprint(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`var admi = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'title') and contains(text(),'Administration')]"));`

You were almost there.

Answer (score 0):

If the `span` element is the only element on the page with the ClassName "title", you could just get the element by ClassName:

```
IWebElement admin = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("title"));
```

If the `span` element is not the only element with the ClassName "title", but is the only element with that ClassName under its parent, you can get the parent element then the `span` element:

```
IWebElment admin = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("item-inner")).FindElement(By.ClassName("title"));
```

Otherwise, I would follow the advise of others using the XPath. Usually I try to use other methods of finding elements because XPath can be slow or unreliable.